# How to Start Multiple SWF Workflows?

Tags: java, amazon-swf

I am writing a SWF Workflow Starter class in Java. The purpose of the class is to use a WorkflowClientExternalFactory to do a getClient() call, then use the WorkflowClientExternal to start my workflow. Here is the basic layout:

```
public class MyWorkflowStarter {
    private final MyWorkflowClientExternalFactory factory;

    public MyWorkflowStarter(MyWorkflowClientExternalFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void startyMyWorkflow (String input) {
        final MyWorkflowClientExternal client = this.factory.getClient();
        client.init(String input);  // init() is a @Execute method in the workflow;
    }
}
```

Now I have a list of Strings and I want to start a list of workflow, each workflow will take in a String to do its work.

My question is: does the startMyWorkflow-fn in MyWorkflowStarter class take in a list of String, and use a for-loop, each loop generate a client to call init fn; Or should I write a method in a new class, which will takes in a list String inputs, call MyWorkflowStarter a list of amount of times?

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks a lot!

```
// Alternatively I could have a workflow and a list of activities, but I want the option of starting a list workflows.
```

Comment: Is this Java or C#? Tag the right language to reach more specific people.

Comment: Java. Already tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SWF point of view it doesn't really matter. To start a workflow getClient() and client.init should be executed for each element of the list. But where this code lives is up to you.

Comment: Make sense. thanks! To be sure - so, let s say my list of input has 5 elements and I want 5 workflows, then 5 MyWorkflowClientExternal client will be created, because MyWorkflowClientExternalFactory.getClient() will be called five times. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Each of the clients can be used to send signal or cancel its correspondent workflow execution.